# Is it possible to build my application with Apache ant and build my unit tests with gradle?

Tags: ant, gradle, build

The current project I am working on is built using apache ant, but I wanted to build my unit tests with gradle as we will be eventually be moving everything over to a gradle build system. I was wondering if anyone has done this before and how the implemented it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps use the [Ant integration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) to build jars and use `flatDir` to make them test dependencies. Other ideas that I can think of are very one-off and may not be worth the trouble, as the above would let you migrate piecemeal.

Comment: Oh sweet, that's actually exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks, Ben!